# After using the renderDatatable command, is it possible to then transform that table into its own data frame?

Tags: r, shiny

I need to create bar plots from reactive data within a renderDatatable command, so I need that table in data.frame format to do so. Is it possible to do this? 
So far I have tried:

```
    tableAB <- reactive({tableA})
    mydata <- data.frame(tableAB)
```

I get the error

> "cannot coerce class ""reactive"" to a data.frame"

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the data to be displayed in the data table to a data frame? I would than use the created data frame as data to be rendered in the data table. After filtering the data table trough the user interface the "input$tableId_rows_all" could be used to get the row indices and use those indices to filter the data frame before plotting.

Does it help?

This is an example how you can use datatable to filter a data frame for plotting:

```
    # ui.R #        
    library(shiny)
    library(DT)


    fluidPage(
            title = 'DataTables Information',
            h1('A client-side table'),
            fluidRow(
                           DT::dataTableOutput('irisTable')
                           ),
            fluidRow(
                    plotOutput("irisPlot")
            )
    )

library(shiny)
library(DT)



shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


    # render the table (with row names)
    output$irisTable = DT::renderDataTable(iris, 
    server = FALSE,  caption = "Column sum example", 
                                    filter = "top")
    output$irisPlot <- renderPlot({
            gg <- ggplot(iris[input$irisTable_rows_all, ], 
             aes(x =   Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) 
            gg <- gg + geom_point()
            print(gg)
    })
```

})

Comment: I assumed that somehow the data you use to fill the datatable is not coming from a data frame and that that was the reason you needed to dump the datatable into a data frame. I have edited my answer  with an example of plotting a data frame filtered with datatable.